# Prove dimension of sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$ where $\dim(U)=n-1$, $\dim(W)=n-3$
 and $n\geq 3$

Prove that $\dim(U\cap W)\geq n-3$

I used the property that both $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$. So $U+W$ is also the subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Hence, I get
$$\dim(U+W)\leq n$$

By using the property 
$$\dim(U\cap W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U+W),$$

I can only get 
$$\dim(U\cap W)\geq n-4.$$

So which part I did wrong? Or the question have mistake?

Comment: You are right, if $n=4$ then $U=\Bbb R^3$, i.e. $(x,y,z,0)\in\Bbb R^4$, and $V=\left(\Bbb R^3\right)^\perp$, i.e. $(0,0,0,t)\in\Bbb R^4$. This gives the intersection dimension $0=n-4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=4$, then taking $U$ as the vector space generated by $e_1,e_2$ and $e_3$, and $V$ the subspace generated by $e_4$, we have $\dim(U)= 3=n-1$, $\dim(V)=1=n-3$ and $U\cap V=\{0\}$, hence $\dim(U\cap V)=n-4$.

Comment: So am i correct? since the inequality i had proved is different from requirement of question

Comment: The example show that in general you cannot do better than the below bound $n-4$ (for $n\geqslant 4$).

Comment: So do $n=3$ valid for the example?

Comment: When $n=3$, the subspace $W$ is trivial hence so is $U\cap V$.